# Что означает шина(bus) в программировании?

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучая исходники, столкнулся с абстрактным понятием **шина** или **bus**. Т.к. огромный python-пакет завязан на этом понятии, мне трудно уловить суть. Не могли бы вы, товарищи трукодеры разжевать это понятие в программировании? Гугл посылает на схемотехническое определение шины.

Comment: [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F) уже читали?

Comment: @MaxU, дело оказалось в незнании паттернов

Comment: Если коротко, то это один из вариантов IPC.

Answer (score 3):

Под **шиной** подразумевался класс "Издатель" из паттерна "[Издатель-подписчик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))" на события шины навешивались обработчики и при возникновении события в "издателе", вызывались методы подписчики на это событие.

Comment: Хм, вы уверены, что это та шина, о которой спрашивает ТС? Может быть, он имеет в виду шину данных или шину адреса процессора?

Comment: @VladD я и есть ТС, я просто сам допер до решения)

Comment: Упс :) Окей, тогда, думаю, вы правильно поняли вопрос :-D

Comment: @VladD: если я из гугла пришёл, то так как я мыслей автора вопроса читать не умею, то ответ должен отвечать на вопрос как написан, а не как он в голове автора выглядит (на такой широкий вопрос, следует широкий ответ писать).

Comment: @jfs я насколько понял, в программировании нет понятия шина(только в физ.устройствах), под шиной в архитектуре приложения стоит подразумевать то, что я написал в ответе.

Comment: это всё равно что сказать, что в программировании окон нет (что windows только физические могут быть). Вы наверно никогда bus error не получали (как sigbus сигнал). Шина это общий компонент, которые другие компоненты связывает внутри/вне компьютера/ов —это понятие применимо как к железу так и ПО. Шина это более общее понятие нежели конкретный "Издатель-подписчик" шаблон—использование bus (в значении message broker) это то как этот шаблон может быть реализован.

Comment: @jfs, ну что вы придираетесь? В программировании BUS -- просто вариант IPC.

Comment: Можете также почитать [Введение в D-BUS](https://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/dbus_intro.txt.html)